# I downloaded stip-2.0 linux, and i try to execute "script.sh" , but this error occurs ./bin/stipdet:1: ./bin/stipdet:syntax error:"(" unexpected

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in $(seq 1 8) 
do
    echo $i
    ./bin/stipdet -i ./BTP/video-list$i.txt -vpath ./BTP/ -fpath ./BTP/ -o ./BTP/traffic-junction-externalstip$i.txt -mode 1 -vis no
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there are hidden characters in the script. May be you copied file from Windows...

Try:

```
dos2unix script.sh
```

And then try to execute again.